# How to access S3 bucket from the credentials provided by amazon cognito?

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I am using amazon s3 bucket to upload my image. I got a warning mail from google that says my AWS credentials were exposed. So now i am replacing the code and use amazon cognito.

I am unable to access the bucket. The error says access is denied.

Here is my code:

```
 credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            context, // get the context for the current activity
            "xxxxxxx", // your AWS Account id
            "ap-southeast-1:3d4e113d-4cd3-47ac-b5ef-xxxxxxxxxx", // your identity pool id
            "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/Cognito_trackusersUnauth_Role",// an authenticated role ARN
            "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/Cognito_trackusersAuth_Role", // an unauthenticated role ARN
            Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1 //Region
    );


    s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
    s3.setEndpoint("s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com");
```

This is where it says acess denied:

```
 List<Bucket> buckets = s3.listBuckets();
```

Comment: did you attach the s3 bucket access policy to your cognito auth role?

Comment: Yes i did that for and gave two permissions of read and write.

Comment: What about list all buckets?

Comment: Done that too.. funny thing is when i remove the line of listing the buckets.. the transfer shows complete and a url is created but there is nothing uploaded.

Comment: That is indeed weird. Try playing around with the policy. Temporarily give it s3fullaccess and see if it works so you can confirm it is a policy issue and nothing is wrong with your code. Unfortunately I work only with python SDK for aws and am unfamiliar with android functionality.